# Codeception организация тестирования приемочных тестов

Tags: php, symfony, тестирование, codeception

Проект создан на `symfony4` с недавних пор начали внедрять в приложение тесты `unit` и `acceptance`. Для этого выбрали `Codeception` и `selenium` для приемочных тестов.
Приемочными тестами будет тестироваться админка, в которой много страниц со списками, добавлением, фильтрами и тд. Так как приемочные тесты тестируют то что видит пользователь, то в админке не протестируешь например списки с данными, так как данные будут меняться.

**Каким образом организовывается правильно тестирование приемочных тестов?**

Я думаю что следует создать ещё одну бд в которой продублировать таблицы и подготовить для них фикстуры(тестовые данные), и проверять уже по ним. Так как тестовых данных придётся создать очень много (проект уже большой), то я решил сначала спросить совета у вас чтобы не наделать лишнего что не будет оправдано.

Подскажите как бы вы сделали в таком случае?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Я думаю что следует создать ещё одну бд в которой продублировать таблицы и подготовить для них фикстуры(тестовые данные), и проверять уже по ним.

Все верно. Именно так я советую вам поступить.

1. Чтобы написать нормальные приемочные тесты вам надо четко знать, что на момент запуска теста находится в бд - фикстуры нужны именно для этого.
2. Вам нужен минимальный объем данных в бд. Минимум, который необходим для прохождения теста. Если тестовая бд будет больших объемов - тесты будут проходить долго. Хороший тест - независим от предыдущего теста - то есть может быть запущен отдельно. Это значит, что очищать тестовую бд и накатывать фикстуры заново вам придется перед каждым тестом. Скорость - одна из проблем приемочных тестов.
3. Поддерживать тестовую бд не так сложно. При каждом обновлении структуры базы надо прогонять миграции еще и на тестом дампе.

Comment: Сделал точно так же как вы и описали :)